# What is the tick or apostrophe character for in Ada?

Tags: syntax, operators, ada

Very basic question, but just reading through source code and trying to tell what the `'` is for and how it differs from `.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `'` character is used to introduce an *attribute*.

For example, `Integer'Last` is the largest value of type `Integer`, and `Float'Digits` is the decimal precision of type `Float`.

The complete list of language-defined attributes is in Annex K of the Ada Reference Manual.

It's also part of the syntax of qualified expressions, such as `Some_Type'(expression)`.

The `.` character is used, among other things, to introduce a record component name, such as `Obj.Comp`, where `Obj` is a record variable and `Comp` is a component of that record.

Attributes are defined by the language or by the implementation; component names are defined when the record type is defined.

The apostrophe is also used to delimit character literals: `'x'`.

Comment: I see, thank you. You say it's language/implementation defined--I can't make my own attributes?

Comment: @JCooper: I haven't used Ada in a while. Last time I looked, there was no way to define your own attributes.

Comment: No way t define your own attributes - you can overwrite only 'Write, 'Read, 'Input, 'Output (used for Ada.Streams.Stream_IO).

Comment: @darkestkhan - One fine day they will allow overriding of `'image` as well.

Comment: @T.E.D. That would be nice but how do you imagine 'Image of access type?

Comment: And the tick is used for Qualified expressions: Some_Type'(expression), Some_Type'Aggregate

Comment: @darkestkhan: `'Image` of an access type could be defined to be an implementation-defined string, so that `'Image` and `'Value` are inverses. It might also make sense to specify a specific string for a null access value, probably `"null"`.